# How to add months to a particular date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I just hope this question won't be marked as a duplicate because I've seen similar questions on stackoverflow but they all talk about adding days to the date, The problem here is that i want to add some particular months to a particular date which is gotten from my database I've tried adding it using `strtotime()` but the date just returns 1st January 1970, the code looks like this

```
<?php echo date('jS F Y', strtotime("$date +1 month")); ?>

//This is the value of date
$date = $student->date;
```

How to I add months to this particular date? Please note that the date is a timestamp in my database.Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `$date`? And adding days and months is not any different.

Comment: The value of date is the retrieved timestamp field from the database,i've edited my question though

Comment: Show an actual *value*. Not how you get that value. `echo $date;`

Comment: when i echoed $date i got a bunch of values but the first one looks like this 1412765176, i believe the 14 stands for 2014 right?

Comment: Nope. That's a unix timestamp. That's the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Unix timestamp, not an actual date. Here I use the DateTime class to create a datetime object using that Unix timestamp. Then I can add a month to it and format the output.

```
$date = new DateTime('@'.$student->date);
$date->modify('+1 month');
echo $date-format('jS F Y');
```

If you want to stick to using `date()` and `strtotime()` you would use this:

```
echo date("jS F Y", strtotime("+1 month", $student->date));
```

`strtotime()` would take the starting date as the second parameter and then how you wish to modify it as your first parameter.

Comment: Thanks john, i tried the second option you gave and it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php),

But the just of it is the $date->add function. It allows you to add any amount of time to a timestamp using a DateInterval. Its a little tricky to get used to but here are a  couple of examples:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT10H30S'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P7Y5M4DT4H3M2S'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
?>
```

which outputs:

```
2000-01-01 10:00:30
2007-06-05 04:03:02
```

The date interval is formatted in years months days hours minuets seconds, simply put in the amount you want and it will add it, so in your case:

```
<?php
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP's `strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function allows for a second parameter that allows you to set a relative date.

If you would like to add a month to tomorrow, here's how:

```
<?php

echo date("jS F Y", strtotime("+1 month", strtotime("2014-10-09")));

// returns: 9th November 2014
```